# in mysql my distinct query not working?

Tags: mysql

in the below image I'm using

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(name),date,reporting,leaving from attendance where date='2016-09-01
```

and I'm still getting repeating names. Why?

[image]

Comment: use backticks like this select DISTINCT(`name`),`date`,`reporting`,`leaving` from attendance where `date` ='2016-09-01';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your all rows have distinct data apart from Name column if you want only distinct names then you can get it with help of Aggregate functions, you can use MIN or MAX as per your business requirement

```
SELECT Name,MAX(date),MAX(reporting),MAX(leaving) 
FROM attendance 
WHERE date='2016-09-01'
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

When using DISCTINCT, MySQL uses all columns as grouping factor. If you want group by only one column and get all corresponding column values, use GROUP BY instead

```
SELECT name, date, reporting, leaving FROM attendance GROUP BY name WHERE ...
```

Comment: what if I only want distinct names + all other columns and exclude those which are nor distinct

Comment: Doesn't the query i posted above do the job? It will group by name as you want and return all columns from one of grouped rows.